# Mock an imported Component that is passed in as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component `ExternalComponent` which comes from a different module fetched via another

configuration js file. This is then passed in as a prop into the Component I am testing as follows.

```js
const LocalComponent = ({
  externalComponent: ExternalComponent, // imported Component coming in as a prop
}) => {
  const onChange = (index) => {
    console.log('test);
    SetData1();
    SetData2();
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.ExternalComponent}>
      <ExternalComponent
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LocalComponent;
```

I am trying to test that the `onChange` works via following test using mount.

But unable to do so ending up with following error.

> Uncaught [Error: mockConstructor(...): Nothing was returned from
> render.  This usually means a return statement is missing.

shallow works fine but I am looking to do the test via mount as I am checking the onChange.

Is there a way around this? Cos I can't just mock it as follows since this is not a Component inside my project.

```
// not gonna work, is an imported Component, not in my paths. 
jest.doMock('./ExternalComponent', () => {
  const ExternalComponent = () => <div />;
  return ExternalComponent;
});
```

This is the test that is failing with above error.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import LocalComponent from './LocalComponent';

describe('LocalComponent', () => {

  const mockSetData1 = jest.fn();
  const mockSetData2 = jest.fn();
  const mockExternalComponent = jest.fn();

  const defaultProps = {
    externalComponent: mockExternalComponent,
    SetData1: mockSetData1,
    SetData2: mockSetData2
  };

  const shallowRender = props => shallow(<LocalComponent {...defaultProps} {...props} />);
  const mountRender = props => mount(<LocalComponent {...defaultProps} {...props} />);

  // works fine since using shallow
  it('should render', () => {
    const rendered = shallowRender();
    expect(rendered).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  // FAILING TEST
  it('should render via mount too', () => {
    const rendered = mountRender(); // this breaks with above error

    // trying to achieve following test, currently unavailable.
    rendered.find('.ExternalComponent').simulate('click');
    expect(mockSetData1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockSetData2).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ExternalComponent` props, it seems that your function `onChange` is triggered when External's function `onChange` is triggered. I assume that the onChange function in the ExternalComponent is linked to an input, with a `value` prop, and that the methods `SetData1` and `SetData2` come from props. (Aren't they missing in your `LocalComponent` props ?)

To trigger it, in your test, you should simulate the "change" action rather than the "click" action in your ExternalComponent.
Updating this, you should have the following:

```js
it('should render via mount too', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<LocalComponent {...defaultProps} />

  wrapper.find('.ExternalComponent').simulate('change', { target: { value: "newValue" } });
  expect(mockSetData1).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mockSetData2).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```